# Lua Curl catch Timeout

Tags: curl, lua

I have creted a lua script requesting vi curl a JSON response from a server.  This is the code:

```
local buffer = {}
local headers = {
    "Content-Type: application/json"
}
url = "https://apiserver/fsapi/json_emcontacts?username=10001&domain=my.domain.com"
local c = curl.easy {
    url         = url,
    ssl_verifypeer = false,
    ssl_verifyhost = false,
    httpheader  = headers,
    [curl.OPT_TIMEOUT] = 2,
}
c:setopt_writefunction(table.insert, buffer)
local ok, err = c:perform()
if ok then
    local status = c:getinfo_response_code()
    if status == 200 then
        consoleLog("info", "API GET JSON OK\n")
        local response = json.decode(table.concat(buffer))
        consoleLog("info", "Data = "..response['item1'].."\n")
    else
        consoleLog("info", "API GET JSON FAIL , status code = "..status.."\n")
    end
else
    consoleLog("info", "API Call Timeout\n")
end
```

I'm using the "[curl.OPT_TIMEOUT]" to set a timeout for 2 secs.  Seems to be working ok, but i'm not able to catch the event when the timeout is complete.... so i'm unable to do actions when this happend.
Does someone knows how to print some log or do something when the timeout is complete?
Thanks in advance.

Ricardo

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figured out.  You have to call pcall in order to catch the error from timeout.
I added this

```
local ok, err = pcall(function() c:perform() end)
```

With this i'm able to catch the error in the else like this :

```
print("API Call - Curl Error No "..err:no().." - "..err:msg().."\n")
```

Hope could be help for others....

Ricardo

Comment: Rather than defining that anonymous function, you could also do `pcall(c.perform, c)` instead.